# Can changes to grid-template-columns be animated with transitions?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm using CSS grids and trying to get a smooth close (width=0) to a column when the screen gets smaller.

```css
.red {
  grid-area: red;
  background-color: #e00025;
}

.green {
  grid-area: green;
  background-color: #bdf681;
}
.blue {
  grid-area: blue;
  background-color: #d3e1f6;
}
.animate {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.xWrapper {
  display:grid;
  width:100vw;
  height:calc(100vh - 10px);
  grid-gap:1em;
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
          "red green blue";
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .xWrapper {
    grid-template-columns:0 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "red green blue";
  }
  .red {
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="xWrapper animate">
  <div class="red">
      Red. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consectetur
      cursus velit, sed cursus erat. Integer scelerisque odio a consectetur laoreet.
      Nam at ante ultricies, volutpat risus vitae, interdum risus.
  </div>

  <div class="green">
      Green. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consectetur
      cursus velit, sed cursus erat. Integer scelerisque odio a consectetur laoreet.
      Nam at ante ultricies, volutpat risus vitae, interdum risus. Suspendisse
      sollicitudin odio a felis ornare, nec elementum velit convallis.
  </div>

  <div class="blue">
      Blue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consectetur
      cursus velit, sed cursus erat. Integer scelerisque odio a consectetur laoreet.
      Nam at ante ultricies, volutpat risus vitae, interdum risus. Suspendisse
      sollicitudin odio a felis ornare, nec elementum velit convallis. Vestibulum
      at imperdiet lorem. Sed consectetur pretium nisi, malesuada ullamcorper nibh viverra
      vel.
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see smooth transitions on the green and blue columns changing size but when a red column disappears it seems to snap closed, as seen on http://www.cssdesk.com/xRDXJ

I want the red column to animate to width:0
Is there a way to make this happen?

Thanks
Abe